# Crash after converting Activity to fragment in Async task

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, classcastexception

I had an activity class which I converted it to a fragment class. I'm getting an error in my onPostExecute of my Async task.

```
 private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            displayData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            try {
                Collections.sort(mData);
            } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                LOG.warn("Illegal state exception, ignoring it {}", ise);
            }
            PrintStockAdapter adapter = new PrintStockAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mData);
            details.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The error is happening here,

```
    details.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Log,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:538)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:524)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:468)
                                                                              at com.app.forms.InventoryReportFragment$FetchData.onPostExecute(InventoryReportFragment.java:253)
                                                                              at com.app.forms.InventoryReportFragment$FetchData.onPostExecute(InventoryReportFragment.java:236)
```

Variable details is a listview.     `private ListView details;`

Where did I go wrong when migrating the activity to a fragment? This crash happens every time the async task runs.

Comment: issue in casting so please provide your whole code

Comment: What is the declaration of PrintStockAdapter? Particularly what does it extend or implement?

Comment: PrintStockAdapter extends to a custom adapter ListAdapter<>

Comment: Crash is happening at details.setAdapter(adapter)